# sliding effect using jQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow

how can one achieve the effect (sliding) in the link below?

http://www.indochino.com/customizations/display/1230898280?productAdded=1

How would I go about designing this? Would I align all the divs next to each other and wrap them in a centered div or required width?

I would like to use jQuery to achieve this...are there any decent plugins that will do the majority of the work as I am new to web development....

Answer (score 0):

If using [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), as mentioned here, is not enough, the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/) package is well-developed and documented. It will do exactly what you're looking for.

For example, check out the [accordion demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/):

```
$('.accordion .head').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('slow');
    return false;
}).next().hide();
```

Comment: That's greate but I need smething that will slide a div horizontally

Answer (score 0):

you could use the approach you're mentioned. See here for a list of similar jquery plugins: http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-super-useful-jquery-content-slider-scripts-and-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Your link does not work but I think you are looking for jquery.slideup or slidedown methods
http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

you can also look at jquery css animation